# How to put a navigation controller inside a tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, listview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am making an app with a tab bar controller and it will have a listView inside of it. When you click on that listView it will lead to another view with a webView. I have found a few answers on stackoverflow on this exact topic but none of them were using the storyboard.  Heres a picture of what i need to accomplish:

My tab bar is capable of displaying the list view but when i click on an option it crashes and here is what it says: "Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController." By the way this is an RSS feed app, thats why there is a webView.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my own problem.

1) Select the initial View.

2)Click on Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great solution. So simple!